# Where is executable file after compiling a c program in ubuntu?

Tags: c, linux, windows, ubuntu, executable

While compiling a C file in windows I get three files a .c file a .o file and a .exe file, now if i want to distribute my program I will give .exe file. But after compiling a .c in ubuntu I can't find the executable file which will run directly on other system by just clicking it.

Comment: you can find `a` file, and in ubuntu(linux), there is no file extension, or that is not important

Comment: you can control the executable name with `-o my_exe` option in the compiler/linker command line

Comment: What command are you using to build the program (meaning, what did you type at the command line)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default file name is `a.out`, but you can specify another filename with `gcc a.c -o my_executable`.